# Three dimensional df

Tags: pandas

I have a df

```
Month     A    B    C
Jan 23    5    7    3
Feb 23    8    10   8
```

From each column I want to make, in this case, three dfs.  I have also introduced the 20230808 date.

DfA

```
          Jan23   Feb23
20230808    5       8
```

DfB

```
          Jan23   Feb23
20230808    7       10
```

DfC

```
          Jan23   Feb23
20230808    3      8
```

This is just a sample and have many columns into df.

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? depending on number of rows/columns you'll end up getting a lot of dataframes. It might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to do this is unclear, by you can easily reshape and split each row:

```
tmp = df.set_index('Month').T.rename_axis(columns=None)

dfs = [tmp.loc[[x]].set_axis(['20230808']) for x in tmp.index]
```

Output:

```
[          Jan 23  Feb 23
 20230808       5       8,
           Jan 23  Feb 23
 20230808       7      10,
           Jan 23  Feb 23
 20230808       3       8]
```